# DEPLOYMENT FAILED with Windows Azure with BitBuket

Tags: azure

I have a few projects that I deploy to Azure through BitBucket. I just created a brand new ASP.NET MVC 4 project and I get the following error when I try to deploy:

```
Command: C:\DWASFiles\Sites\TrainConjugate\VirtualDirectory0\site\deployments\tools\deploy.cmd
Handling .NET Web Application deployment.
C:\DWASFiles\Sites\TrainConjugate\VirtualDirectory0\site\repository\TrainConjugate\TrainConjugate.csproj(623,3): error MSB4019: The imported project "C:\DWASFiles\Sites\TrainConjugate\VirtualDirectory0\site\repository\packages\Microsoft.Bcl.Build.1.0.6\tools\Microsoft.Bcl.Build.targets" was not found. Confirm that the path in the <Import> declaration is correct, and that the file exists on disk.
An error has occurred during web site deployment.
Handling .NET Web Application deployment.
C:\DWASFiles\Sites\TrainConjugate\VirtualDirectory0\site\repository\TrainConjugate\TrainConjugate.csproj(623,3): error MSB4019: The imported project "C:\DWASFiles\Sites\TrainConjugate\VirtualDirectory0\site\repository\packages\Microsoft.Bcl.Build.1.0.6\tools\Microsoft.Bcl.Build.targets" was not found. Confirm that the path in the <Import> declaration is correct, and that the file exists on disk.
An error has occurred during web site deployment.
D:\kuduservice\wwwroot\bin\scripts\starter.cmd C:\DWASFiles\Sites\TrainConjugate\VirtualDirectory0\site\deployments\tools\deploy.cmd
```

I'm a little lost on this one. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a workaround here:
https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/788981/microsoft-bcl-build-targets-causes-project-loading-to-fail

Easy fix... Until I upgrade or something and forget to make this change...